# Illegal reflective access while running simulation in UnetStack

Tags: java, groovy, unetstack

`bin/unet samples/2-node-network.groovy` running this line throws the following error.

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1 (file:/home/mohanraju/Documents/Research/unet-community-3.4.0/unet-3.4.0/lib/groovy-2.5.9.jar) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
```

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in IllegalArgumentException and see what line of source triggers the exception?

Comment: I changed the java version and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a Java version problem.

Can you check which version of Java you're running by typing the following command in your terminal

```
java -version
```

UnetStack v3.x.x only support Java8. You can install it for your https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases?version=8

Comment: java -version returns 11.0.16. I will install java 8 and check.

Comment: After installing Java 8, it is working fine.